# Error "Exception while executing function" from Azure Service Bus Listener

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We use an **Azure Service Bus** to post all of our requests from our *Xamarin mobile app*. The **Azure Service Bus** is bound to an **Azure Function** which is triggered each time a requests hits the **Azure Service Bus**.

We have found that we are getting errors from this **Azure Function** when we send data above a certain size. We can send up to 800 records without a problem but when we send >=850 records we get the following error:

> [Error] Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.ServiceBusQueueTrigger. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred.
>   A task was canceled.

The service that is being invoked is an *ASP.NET Web API* RESTful service that saves the data records into a database. This doesn't generate any errors at all.

Here is my Azure Function code.

```
#r "JWT.dll"
#r "Common.dll"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {message.MessageId}");

    if (message != null)
    {
        Common.Entities.MessageObjectEntity messageObject = message?.GetBody<Common.Entities.MessageObjectEntity>();
        string msgType = messageObject?.MessageType;
        var msgContent = messageObject?.MessageContent;
        log.Info($"Message type: {msgType}");

        double timestamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        string subscriber = "MYSUBSCRIBER";
        string privatekey = "MYPRIVATEKEY";
        Dictionary<string, object> payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"iat", timestamp},
            {"subscriber", subscriber}
        };
        string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, privatekey, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = $"http://myexamplewebservices.azurewebsites.net/api/routingtasks?formname={msgType}";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(subscriber, token);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent((string)msgContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
            var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);

            if (response == null)
            {
                log.Info("Null response returned from request.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    log.Info("Successful response returned from request.");
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Info($"Unsuccessful response returned from request: {response.Result.StatusCode}.");
                }
            }
        }
        log.Info("Completing message.");
    }
}
```

This code has been working for several years and works across all our other apps / web sites.

Any ideas why we're getting errors wehen we post large amounts of data to our **Azure Service Bus** / **Azure Function**?

Comment: would you like to share your AZFunction code ?

Comment: @ImranArshad updated to include code example

Comment: I have posted my answer with explanation below. Probably httpclient is the issue

Answer (score 1):

It may caused by "new httpclient", there is a limit to how quickly system can open new sockets so if you exhaust the connection pool, you may get some errors. You can refer to this link: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

And could you please share some more error message ?

Comment: The request still results in one call to the service. The difference being that the size of the request is increasingly larger. So I'm not making multiple requests, but making larger requests. The payload to the service involves a list of items that gets increasingly bigger as more data is sent with the request to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are creating httpclient connection on each request which possibly be causing this issue. Httpclient creates  a socket connection underneath it and has hard limit on it. Even when you dispose it it remains there for couple of mins that can't be used. A good practice is to create single static httpclient connection and reuse it. I am attaching some documents for you to go through. 
[AzFunction Static HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#connection-limit) , [Http Client Working](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) , [Improper instantiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)

Comment: The request still results in one call to the service. The difference being that the size of the request is increasingly larger. So I'm not making multiple requests, but making larger requests. The payload to the service involves a list of items that gets increasingly bigger as more data is sent with the request to be processed.

Comment: actually i am referring to the httpclient in your code. that is calling your azurewebsite api. you are not using static httpclient and docs i shared refer to that problem.  you definitely need to look into that one and could be cause of this issue. there is limit of 600 sockets i guess and after that it will fail. on the other note which service bus sku are you using? standard or premium  . how large is data that you are sending?

Comment: I assumed you were referring to the HttpClient code. While the suggestions mentioned are certainly very useful, I don't think they're the cause of the error I am seeing. A single request should not invoke the error I am seeing. If I had a loop that was making multiple requests then that would be expected, but I get the error when making a single call. The payload to the request however can be very large, and it these large payloads where I am seeing the error occur. We are on pay-as-you-go plan.

Comment: how many request per second or a minute you make or when you encounter error?